# Undefined reference to BLAS functions when using LAPACK compiled by myself

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, gfortran, lapack, blas

**lapack compilation output**

```
-->   LAPACK TESTING SUMMARY  <--
Processing LAPACK Testing output found in the TESTING directory
SUMMARY                 nb test run     numerical error     other error  
================    =========== =================   ================  
REAL                882293      0   (0.000%)    0   (0.000%)    
DOUBLE PRECISION    1279265     0   (0.000%)    0   (0.000%)    
COMPLEX             329049      0   (0.000%)    0   (0.000%)    
COMPLEX16           517308      6313    (1.220%)    4380    (0.847%)    

--> ALL PRECISIONS  3007915     6313    (0.210%)    4380    (0.146%)
```

**My program error**

```
In function `dgetrf_':
dgetrf.f:(.text+0x3cb): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
dgetrf.f:(.text+0x4a2): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
/home/niyaa/jsz/liblapack.so(dgetrs.o): In function `dgetrs_':
dgetrs.f:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
dgetrs.f:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
dgetrs.f:(.text+0x356): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
dgetrs.f:(.text+0x3c3): undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
/home/niyaa/jsz/liblapack.so(zgeev.o): In function `zgeev_':
zgeev.f:(.text+0xe96): undefined reference to `dznrm2_'
zgeev.f:(.text+0xec2): undefined reference to `zdscal_'
zgeev.f:(.text+0xf13): undefined reference to `idamax_'
```

**make file for lapack build**

```
cd -
FORTRAN  = gfortran
OPTS     = -O2 -frecursive
DRVOPTS  = $(OPTS)
NOOPT    = -O0 -frecursive
LOADER   = gfortran
LOADOPTS =

BLASLIB      = -lblas -L/home/niyaa/Downloads/lapack-3.7.0/BLAS/SRC
CBLASLIB     = /home/niyaa/Downloads/lapack-3.7.0/BLAS/SRC/libcblas.so
LAPACKLIB    = liblapack.so
TMGLIB       = libtmglib.a
LAPACKELIB   = liblapacke.a
```

I am able to compile the code with the system provided lapacklib.so in the /usr/lib/ directory.

Comment: So how do you compile it? How does the full command look like? In which directory? How do you tell to gfortran where is LAPACK and BLAS?

Comment: From which Linux package does the system LAPACK come?

Comment: Thanks, @VladimirF .. i am compiling using gfortran -O3 -o  myExe.x mycodes.f90  -L/home/niyaa/test/ -llpack
if i just copy the file /usr/lib/liblapack.so to the test folder it comiled. If i copy my build liblapack.so it gave above mentioned errors.

Comment: i am using ubuntu  14.04 and i dont know how to see the version of the lapack lib in  the /usr/lib/ .  The lapack i build is the lasted version 3.7.0

Comment: It is in your Ubuntu package manager, just find the name of the package that contains the library. But, foremost, just using `-llapack` is not enough. You must also use `-lblas`.